# A slot similar to mini PCI-E or M.2, but has 11+22 pins. What is it?

Tags: pci-express, thinkcentre

What kind of a slot is this, please?

It's in Lenovo Thinkcentre M920q. I did check the manual and it seems that the optional Wi-Fi card goes here (which I do not have), but it does not say what slot this is. And I couldn't find the correct keywords to google for the answer based off the pin count.

[image]

Comment: Lenovo says its a M.2 slot only for wifi, scroll down for Tech Specs>>>>>https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre/m-series-tiny/ThinkCentre-M920q/p/11TC1MTM92Q

Comment: @Moab: so it is electrically M.2, but physically it's nothing standard? Do you think it's impossible to connect other PCI-E devices to this slot, even if I had the right passive adapter?

Comment: Its special for wifi cards only, M2E slot, NGFF M2 standard. There is a M2A slot also, it has the key slot in a different place.>>>>https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-PCs-NGFF-Card-2-4GHz-Bluetooth-Wireless-AC/dp/B07FMKHKQY

Comment: Hell there lots of configurations, scroll down for the chart>>>>>>>>https://www.atpinc.com/blog/what-is-m.2-M-B-BM-key-socket-3

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2

Comment: M.2 Key E:  https://www.delock.de/infothek/M.2/M.2_e.html

Comment: Thank you, @Moab. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: And thank you @wb3, you should also post an answer.

Comment: Great, I will!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M.2 Key E.  This is a more complete explanation of M.2 slots:
delock.de/infothek/M.2/M.2_e.html

[image]